# Does the quartz scheduler run on its own thread?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'd like to use quartz in a project of mine. I know that there is a scheduler and a threadpool for the jobs.

- Does the scheduler continuously run in its own thread and fires off the jobs?
- If I run the app on a 2 core CPU will one core be busy with the scheduling thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, quartz uses at least n+1 threads where 1 is the scheduler thread that is running in an infinite loop sleeping before next task that should be triggered. N is the number of worker threads in the threadpool. You can configure this number using the property `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount`.

Comment: Cheers, I actually grabbed the source and `QuartzSchedulerThread` is pretty self-explanatory :). Their sleeping is rather funky though: `long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long waitTime = now + getRandomizedIdleWaitTime();
                long timeUntilContinue = waitTime - now;
                synchronized(sigLock) {
                 try {
      sigLock.wait(timeUntilContinue);
     } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
     }
                }`

Answer (score 1):

You can see it work by running the stuff through for example Eclipse and then in the debug view you can see the active and sleeping threads of the application.

Quartz will create a configurable pool of threads. Each job will fire in its own thread (of course, otherwise they can't run concurrently). And no, its not a busy loop so the scheduler won't claim a CPU for itself.